# Colormap 2D for a scalar - Matlab

Tags: matlab, 2d, colormap

i'm simulating a wave propogation in time and place. i want to make a colormap of its values for every time step, in space. i mean, i want to make a figure of 2 axes (x and y) and displays the wave's values at those points by color (the wave varible is V).
how can i do it?
i'v tried:

```
for ind1 = 1:length(t)
figure()
trisurf(x1,y1,V(:,ind1),'EdgeColor', 'None', 'facecolor', 'interp');
view(2);
end
```

but i got a message that z (=V) suppose to be a function and not a scalar.
any suggestions?

Comment: What if you use `contourf`? http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/ref/contourf.html

Comment: doesn't work that well. maybe a differnt syntax? have more suggestions?

Comment: Depends what your data is like. Can you give a small example that runs, and which shows your problem. For example, just create random matrices of the appropriate size to be your data. I can't understand what you want from the description in the question, sorry.

Comment: ok!
i've made a delaunay triangulation an the begining, called dts. so, i have a struct with 2 fields: elements and points.
i wrote an algorithm for an action potential propagation, depends in time and space. every time step i calculte the potential (V), in every point.
now, for every time step i want to creat a colormap, that shows the  potential value on every point.
i've got 826 points, and lets say 100 time iterations. V size is 826X100, x size is 826X1, and y is 826X1.

Answer (score 0):

I have two options, I don't think they will be perfect, but it might help.

First, interpolate the data onto a rectangular mesh and use `contourf`:

```
F=scatteredInterp(x,y,V(:,ind1));
X=linspace(min(x),max(x));
Y=linspace(min(y),max(y));
contourf(X,Y,F(X,Y))
```

Secondly, use `scatter` to plot points with varying colour:

```
scatter(x,y,25,V(:,ind1))
```

where the 25 controls the size of each marker, you may have to experiment with it.

Hope that gives you some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

i've made a loop that finally works:

```
clear heart_movie
Vnorm = mat2gray(V(:,1:2000));
x1_new = x1-min(x1)+1;
y1_new = y1-min(y1)+1;

for ind1 = 1:2000
    heart = zeros(max(x1_new),max(y1_new));
    z = Vnorm(:,ind1);
    for ind2 = 1:length(z);
        heart(y1_new(ind2),x1_new(ind2))= z(ind2);
    end
    colormap(jet);
    imagesc(flipud(heart));
end
```